# Are there any pros and cons associated with dvipsnames, svgnames, and x11names in xcolors package?

Tags: color, package-options

The xcolors package mentions three color options in its package documentation at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf. They are `dvipsnames`, `svgnames`, and `x11names`.

I normally use the `dvipsnames` option like this:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

I want to know whether it matters which one of these three options I choose. Is there any obviously preferred option used by most of the LaTeX community or does it just boil down to one's personal preferences?

In other words, to keep this question objective, I want to know if there are any specific pros and cons for each option that we need to be aware of before we decide which option to use with the `xcolor` package?

Comment: They are simply different sets of colors, I use the one(s) which contains the colors I want to use by looking at the list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One difference is that the colours with `dvipsnames` are defined in CMYK, but `svgnames` and `x11names` are defined in RGB. So you might choose `dvipsnames` if your final output is intended for offset or digital print.

This difference leads to a potential pitfall to be aware of when using the `dvipsnames` option of `xcolor`.

By default `pgf` shadings are output in RGB, so unless you explicitly ask for CMYK shadings, you won't get the colours you want in shadings. This is especially noticeable when you have the solid colours at either end of the shading, which can sometimes happen in `beamer` templates.

Consider this MWE demonstrating the issue. Both *Blue* and *LimeGreen* are defined by `dvipsnames` and are in CMYK. The top shading has the wrong colours because it's in RGB. This is what you get unless you explicitly change the colour model to CMYK (e.g., by using `\usepackage[cmyk,dvipsnames]{xcolor}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section*{Natural Colour model}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[Blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \shade[left color=Blue, right color=LimeGreen] (1.25,0) rectangle (3.75,1);
  \fill[LimeGreen] (4,0) rectangle (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{CMYK colour model}

\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[Blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
  \shade[left color=Blue, right color=LimeGreen] (1.25,0) rectangle (3.75,1);
  \fill[LimeGreen] (4,0) rectangle (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Can changing the color model to CMYK affect other things or is it safe to always use it with *dvipsnames*?

Comment: @JoãoBravo, there shouldn't be anything major. Depending on your printer and printer driver, you can sometimes end up with your blacks coming out dark grey. Colours defined in RGB will look different (e.g., compare the colour *green*), but your PDF viewer will give a reasonable approximation of what they will look like when printed.